# How can I use the output of one function as the input of another function?

Tags: python

I am creating a Feistel network. I need to take the phrase "WEAPONS FROM MATH" and split it into groups of 3. The first group is considered the left group while the next group is considered the right group and so forth. The right group goes through the change of C = 7 * P % 26 then becomes the left group for the next round. The original left group does as xor with the new left group then becomes the new right group. The functions are set up to match this.

Part1a separates the phrase into two different groups then sets a variable equal to each individual letter. Part 2a needs to take those variables (l1, l2, l3, r1, r2, r3) and change them as described above. Part 1a only needs to be completed once but part2a will need to happen five times. I have yet to add the five rounds into the program because I'm unable to successfully complete one round. I've tried various methods to get Part2a to read the returned variables from Part1a without success.

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r1' referenced before assignment on line 62 in main.py

```
#Feistel Network

#initalizing variables
k=0

#Creating the sentence
Sentence = "WEAPONS FROM MATH"
def remove(string):
 return string.replace(" ", "")
sentence= remove(Sentence)

#Sitting it into groups of three
Group1L = ""
Group2L = ""
Group3L = ""
Group1R = ""
Group2R = ""
Group3R = "ZZZ"
for i in range (0, len(sentence)):
  if i <3:
    Group1L+= sentence[i];
  if i>=3 and i<6:
    Group1R += sentence[i];
  if i>=6 and i<9:
    Group2L += sentence[i];
  if i>=9 and i<12:
    Group2R += sentence[i];
  if i>=12 and i<15:
    Group3L += sentence[i];


def Part1a(GroupL, GroupR):
    #Spit group into indiviual
    L1 = Group1L[0]
    L2 = Group1L[1]
    L3 = Group1L[2]
    R1 = Group1R[0]
    R2 = Group1R[1]
    R3 = Group1R[2]
    #Convert to decimal 
    l1 = ord(L1) - 64
    l2 = ord(L2) - 64
    l3 = ord(L3) - 64
    r1 = ord(R1) - 64
    r2 = ord(R2) - 64
    r3 = ord(R3) - 64
    
    #testing
    print(L1, L2, L3, R1, R2, R3)
    print(l1, l2, l3, r1, r2, r3)
    
    #return
    return [l1, l2, l3, r1, r2, r3]
 
def Part1b(x):
    #key
    global k
    k+=1
    print(k)
     
    #function
    a = (7 * r1 ) % 26              //This is where I am getting the error
    b = (7 * r2 ) % 26
    c = (7 * r3 ) % 26

    #XOR
    r1 = a ^ l1
    r2 = b ^ l2
    r3 = c ^ l3

    #SetNewValue 
    l3 = a
    l1 = b
    l2 = c

    #testing
    print(a, b, c)
    print(l1, l2, l3, r1, r2, r3)

Part1b(Part1a(Group1L, Group2R))
```

Comment: `Part1b` receives `x` but you never use `x` there. `x` is what contains the resulting list from `Part1a`, from where you want to extract the elements to use, like what you called `r1`. At the moment there is an `r1` in the `Part1b` local scope, but it is assigned later.

Comment: How do get r1 from x? I thought x was just Part1a.

Comment: You can *unpack* (*destructure*) the returned container from `Part1a`. Like with `l1, l2, l3, r1, r2, r3 = x` inside `Part1b`. The values on the left are local to `Part1b` despite having the same name used elsewhere.